# How to get Balance field value from VendorBalanceSummary DAC and show it in Checks and Payments screen in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I want to get balance value from VendorBalanceSummary DAC and show it in Checks and Payments screen. I tried to do this with a selector by passing vendorId. But it gives and error saying "Invalid Object Name VendorBalanceSummary". How Can I Do this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The DAC is a calculated DAC on the vendor screen. I made a quick extension that should work for you.

```
public class APPaymentEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<APPaymentEntry>
{

    [PXCopyPasteHiddenView]
    public PXSelect<PX.Objects.AP.VendorMaint.VendorBalanceSummary> VendorBalance;

    protected virtual IEnumerable vendorBalance()
    {
        //modify to get from current payments vendor, not current vendor.
        List<VendorBalanceSummary> list = new List<VendorBalanceSummary>(1);
        PXSelectBase<APVendorBalanceEnq.APLatestHistory> sel = new PXSelectJoinGroupBy<APVendorBalanceEnq.APLatestHistory,
            LeftJoin<CuryAPHistory, On<APVendorBalanceEnq.APLatestHistory.branchID, Equal<CuryAPHistory.branchID>,
                And<APVendorBalanceEnq.APLatestHistory.accountID, Equal<CuryAPHistory.accountID>,
                And<APVendorBalanceEnq.APLatestHistory.vendorID, Equal<CuryAPHistory.vendorID>,
                And<APVendorBalanceEnq.APLatestHistory.subID, Equal<CuryAPHistory.subID>,
                And<APVendorBalanceEnq.APLatestHistory.curyID, Equal<CuryAPHistory.curyID>,
                And<APVendorBalanceEnq.APLatestHistory.lastActivityPeriod, Equal<CuryAPHistory.finPeriodID>>>>>>>>,
            Where<APVendorBalanceEnq.APLatestHistory.vendorID, Equal<Current<APPayment.vendorID>>>,
            Aggregate<
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.finBegBalance,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyFinBegBalance,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.finYtdBalance,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyFinYtdBalance,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.tranBegBalance,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyTranBegBalance,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.tranYtdBalance,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyTranYtdBalance,

                Sum<CuryAPHistory.finPtdPayments,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.finPtdPurchases,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.finPtdDiscTaken,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.finPtdWhTax,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.finPtdCrAdjustments,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.finPtdDrAdjustments,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.finPtdRGOL,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.finPtdDeposits,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.finYtdDeposits,

                Sum<CuryAPHistory.finPtdRetainageWithheld,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.finYtdRetainageWithheld,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.finPtdRetainageReleased,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.finYtdRetainageReleased,

                Sum<CuryAPHistory.tranPtdPayments,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.tranPtdPurchases,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.tranPtdDiscTaken,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.tranPtdWhTax,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.tranPtdCrAdjustments,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.tranPtdDrAdjustments,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.tranPtdRGOL,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.tranPtdDeposits,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.tranYtdDeposits,

                Sum<CuryAPHistory.tranPtdRetainageWithheld,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.tranYtdRetainageWithheld,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.tranPtdRetainageReleased,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.tranYtdRetainageReleased,

                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyFinPtdPayments,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyFinPtdPurchases,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyFinPtdDiscTaken,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyFinPtdWhTax,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyFinPtdCrAdjustments,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyFinPtdDrAdjustments,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyFinPtdDeposits,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyFinYtdDeposits,

                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyFinPtdRetainageWithheld,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyFinYtdRetainageWithheld,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyFinPtdRetainageReleased,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyFinYtdRetainageReleased,

                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyTranPtdPayments,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyTranPtdPurchases,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyTranPtdDiscTaken,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyTranPtdWhTax,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyTranPtdCrAdjustments,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyTranPtdDrAdjustments,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyTranPtdDeposits,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyTranYtdDeposits,

                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyTranPtdRetainageWithheld,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyTranYtdRetainageWithheld,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyTranPtdRetainageReleased,
                Sum<CuryAPHistory.curyTranYtdRetainageReleased
                >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>(Base);

        VendorBalanceSummary res = new VendorBalanceSummary();
        foreach (PXResult<APVendorBalanceEnq.APLatestHistory, CuryAPHistory> it in sel.Select())
        {
            CuryAPHistory iHst = it;
            Aggregate(res, iHst);
        }
        list.Add(res);


        return list;
    }

    //copied from vendor maintenance
    protected virtual void Aggregate(VendorBalanceSummary aRes, CuryAPHistory aSrc)
    {
        if (!aRes.Balance.HasValue) aRes.Balance = Decimal.Zero;
        if (!aRes.DepositsBalance.HasValue) aRes.DepositsBalance = Decimal.Zero;
        if (!aRes.RetainageBalance.HasValue) aRes.RetainageBalance = Decimal.Zero;

        aRes.VendorID = aSrc.VendorID;
        aRes.Balance += aSrc.FinYtdBalance ?? Decimal.Zero;
        aRes.DepositsBalance += aSrc.FinYtdDeposits ?? Decimal.Zero;
        aRes.RetainageBalance += aSrc.FinYtdRetainageWithheld - aSrc.FinYtdRetainageReleased;
    }

}
```